# Opening an Outlook .msg file with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following code

```
Sub Kenneth_Li()
    Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
    Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    inPath = "C:\Users\SiliconPlus\Desktop\Si+ Contact Lists\Contact_Si+"

    thisFile = Dir(inPath & "\*.msg")
    Do While thisFile <> ""

        'Set Msg = objOL.CreateItemFromTemplate(thisFile)
        'Or
        Set Msg = objOL.OpenSharedItem(thisFile)

        Msg.display

        MsgBox Msg.Subject
        thisFile = Dir
    Loop


    Set objOL = Nothing
    Set Msg = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I use `OpenSharedItem` it gives a run-time error 438 Object doesn't support this property or method.

When I use `CreateItemFromTemplate` I get the following error:

> Cannot open file: AUTO Andy Low Yong Cheng is out of the office (returning 22 09 2014).msg.
>   The file may not exist, you may not have permission to open it, or it may be open in another program.
>   Right-click the folder that contains the file, and then click properties to check your permissions for the folder.

Answer (score 0):

`OpenSharedItem` method is exposed by the `Namespace` object, not `Application`.

```
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set objNs = objOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
objNs.Logon
...
Set Msg = objNs .OpenSharedItem(thisFile)
```

As for the second error, it is pretty unambiguous - the file cannot be found. You must provider a fully qualified file name with the folder path. You are only providing the file name.

Comment: What do u mean fully qualified? As far as i know im only providing C:\Users\SiliconPlus\Desktop\Si+ Contact Lists\Contact_Si+ as the file path.

Comment: Is that the value of the thisFile variable? The error message only contains the file name with no path component.

Comment: lol i still don't get what you are trying to say. Can u elaborate with examples please. thanks!

Comment: yes that is the value of the thisFile variable since i specified the file path.

Comment: Again, is that what you see in the debugger? AFAIK Dir() only returns the file name with no path component. You must use inPath : 

    Set Msg = objOL.OpenSharedItem(inPath & "\"  & thisFile)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% on what you're trying to get at with the code, but try this:

```
Sub LiminalMsgbx()

    Dim outappp, outmaill As Object
    Dim pthh As String
    pthh = "C:\DeskTop\MyTemplate.oft"

  Set outappp = CreateObject ("Outlook.Application")
  Set outmaill = outapp.CreateItemFromTemplate(pthh)   

                With outmaill
                    .display

                    End With
Set outappp = Nothing
Set outmaill = Nothing

End Sub
```

You can also use `.send` instead of `.display`.